# Ajax gives php only 4 numbers of whole value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I give to php page via ajax phone number.
I do subsctrings to convert it from 8 (999) 999-9999 to 9999999999 format

```
var phone=$("#phoneDiv").html();
var phone1=phone.substring(4,7)+phone.substring(9,12)+phone.substring(14,18);
console.log(phone1);
data={phone:phone1,code:code,key:'clientCode'};
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "../editCode.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

In my php I have echo of PHP vars:

```
echo $_POST['phone']." ".$_POST['code']." ".$_POST['key'];
```

here is console output:
922222222 - console.log(phone1)
2222 5555 clientCode - console.log(data)
As you can see only 4 numbers from whole string there. Suggestions?

```
var_dump($_POST)
 array(3) {
  ["phone"]=>
  string(4) "9010"
  ["code"]=>
  string(4) "1234"
  ["key"]=>
  string(10) "clientCode"
}
```

**SAMPLE VALUE OF PHONE:
+7 (999) 999-9999**

Comment: What `var_dump($_POST);` shows you?

Comment: Yep, I've defined it.

Comment: @SergeyScopin give sample value of `phone`?

Comment: Value is 1234 it's ok. Also added sample value

Comment: can you try doing this to clean the phone number instead?  `var phone = "(1) - 999 - 2321 - 23232"; var phone1 = phone.replace(/\D/g,''); `  Actually, that won't change it probably.  But it's prettier... hey, so ` +7 (999) 999-9999` gives you `9010` in `$_POST`?

Comment: 9999999999
gives me 9999 in $_POST=)

Comment: Look at the developer tools of the browser, network tab - how much data is sent to the server. Otherwise you have something on your server-side that cuts the string. Or the part of code is doing something that you do not expect. Or the string that you are sending on server has \x0, for example..

Comment: hah... i dunno why people are downvoting you so badly.  i could understand no upvotes or maybe just one -1 but... ehhh... people must be grumpy tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works for me...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id ='phoneDiv'>+7 (999) 999-9999</div>

<script>

var phone  = $('#phoneDiv').html();
var phone1 = phone.replace(/\D/g,'');

console.log(phone1);

data = {phone:phone1, code:'THEN WHO WAS PHONE?', key:'clientCode'};

$.ajax({
    type:  "POST",
    url:   "../editCode.php",
    data:  data,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

</script>
```

and in editCode.php is just `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>`

Comment: I'll accept your answer. Mistake was rather stupid. I had another $_POST['phone'] var in my config.php. But thanks for replace of non-number char. This variant is better.

Comment: @SergeyScopin - we can't troubleshoot code you don't post... btw.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to replace those substring functions with a simple regular expression match or replace. After too many substrings, various inputs can get confusing to debug. In this case, if you're looking to get only numbers and no non-numeric characters, you can use the following regular expression:

```
phone1 = phone.replace(/\D/g,'')
```

If you're looking to strip all non-numeric characters and the first number, that would be the time to use substrings.

```
phone.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(1, phone.length)
```